# Publishing an Input outside the Form to the Form via name programmatically with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller, angularjs-ng-form, angularjs-forms

I need to publish an Input to a Form, while the Input sits outside the form. I managed to add the input, but the result is not what I excactly need (see the console output)

So I basically adding the outer `input` element to the `form` via `form.$addControl(outerInput)`

```js
const MyApp = angular.module('app', []);

MyApp.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element){
  
    $scope.dataModel = {
      name: 'robert arschfick',
      email: 'blabla',
      age: 25,
      text: 'text'
    };
  
  
    $scope.addOuterInputToForm = function(form, inputID){
      // annoying as hell, I am retrieving the input element;
      var input = angular.element(document.getElementById(inputID))[0];
      
      form.$addControl(input);
      console.log(form);
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="" name="testForm">
    <input type="name" ng-model="dataModel.name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" ng-model="dataModel.email" name="email" required>
    <input type="number" ng-model="dataModel.age">
   
  </form>
  
  <!-- I need to add this input the same way the inner inputs name 
       and email are published to the form, so that it is addressable
       via its name in the form and that it is part of the form.controls
  -->
  <input type="text" required id="inputToAdd" name="text"
         ng-model="dataModel.text">
  <button ng-click="addOuterInputToForm(testForm, 'inputToAdd')">
     Add Control
  </button>
</div>
```

The input is added as a control, but the object looks different and has not all the ng $validators on it. Also I need to add it by name as a property to the form like "email" and "name" are:

[image]

This is the outside input added to the form. It misses all the ng-form attributes see the image after

[image]

This is the inside email input added to the form somehow internally. It has all the ng form properties like $untouched, $prestine etc.

[image]

So what I need is now to somehow fake this internal adding of the outer input programmatically so that the outer input is contained the same way by the form as the inner inputs "email" and "name"

Sorry for my english skills and I hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am very rusty on angular but your question seems to be asking about a specific solution that may not be ideal for the problem you are having. For more information see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/326778)

Comment: @Marie Authors should avoid non-informative link phrases such as: click here, [here](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text), more, read more, etc.

Comment: @Marie you may be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$addControl`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$addControl) method needs the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) of the `<input>`, not the `<input>` element itself.

To get the `ngModelController` of the element, enclose it in a div that has an `ng-form` directive:

```
  <div ng-form="other">
     <input type="text" required id="inputToAdd" name="text"
            ng-model="dataModel.text">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="testForm.$addControl(other.text)">
     Add Control
  </button>
```

### The DEMO

```js
const MyApp = angular.module('app', []);

MyApp.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element){
  
    $scope.dataModel = {
      name: 'robert arschfick',
      email: 'blabla',
      age: 25,
      text: 'text'
    };
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="" name="testForm">
    <input type="name" ng-model="dataModel.name" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" ng-model="dataModel.email" name="email" required>
    <input type="number" ng-model="dataModel.age">
   
  </form>
  
  <!-- I need to add this input the same way the inner inputs name 
       and email are published to the form, so that it is addressable
       via its name in the form and that it is part of the form.controls
  -->
  <div ng-form="other">
     <input type="text" required id="inputToAdd" name="text"
            ng-model="dataModel.text">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="testForm.$addControl(other.text)">
     Add Control
  </button>
</div>
```